# How to fix Metro Message Box Bug, it doesn't read the form owner's size and location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, metroframework

MetroMessageBox doesn't read form owner's size and location which is My Parent Form. MetroMessageBox is declared inside child form. How can I set My MetroMessageBox owner to be the Parent Form?

I've tried using this code:

```
using MetroFramework;

private void TileUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This is my Parent Form
    frmMain fm = new frmMain();
    //This my MetroMessageBox
    MetroMessageBox.Show(fm,"1075","458",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Question);
}
```

Still it doesn't read the Parent Form, but when I use Breakpoint My MetroMessageBox reads the Parent Form and fits on the Parent Form.

This is My MetroMessageBox when I execute the without Breakpoint
[image: This is My MetroMessageBox when I execute the without Breakpoint]
This is My MetroMessageBox when use Breakpoint
[image: This is My MetroMessageBox when use Breakpoint]

Comment: The SQL query in the question you just deleted was bad to begin with, and LINQ is *NOT* a replacement for SQL. If you have to do JOINs in LINQ, you're doing it wrong. LINQ is a language on top of an ORM. An ORM Maps Objects to Relational tables/views. It's the ORM's job to create JOINs from the relations between objects.

Comment: You can fix that query by using a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/), join with it on the Date column and filter by the year column. `DATEDIFF` *prevents* the server from using any indexes

Comment: I'll try to do the solution you gave :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
public async Task ShowInfoDialogAsync(string text)
{
    var metroWindow = App.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow;
    await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Info", text);
}
```

Comment: App and MetroWindow is not defined.

Comment: To help you, we have not enough information. 3 lines of code is not enough.

Comment: You made a mistake. You must call the message box from the active form. You didn't call Show method from MetroWindow instance before calling the message box.

Comment: Can't understand. How do i do that?

Comment: @JamesMatthewVillar before running this code you must call Show() method on your current view if you didn't run yet this.

Comment: I think this code is for MahApps. I'm using MetroFramework :(